# ClassNotFoundException scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcLI$sp

Tags: scala

When using scala 2.10 & specs2 1.11 I have the following error and all the tests are failing:

```
 XXXTest.initializationError failed: scala/runtime/AbstractFunction1$mcLI$sp
 [...]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcLI$sp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading specs2 to 1.14:

```
 "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test"
```